# Error while importing Work Item Type - TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

When I import a Work Item Type from [Team Review](http://teamreview.codeplex.com/), I get this error:

```
TF218007: Cannot import the work item type. It changes fields in team projects
in which you do not have permissions to make changes. Correct this problem by
changing the definition of the work item type so that it does not change the
name or reporting behavior of these fields:
Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate, System.ExternalLinkCount,
System.HyperLinkCount, System.AttachedFileCount
Or obtain permissions to make
changes to these team projects: Project2
Operation failed.
```

What should I change in the WIT definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, check to see if you have administrator priveliges in "Project2."  If that doesn't work, export one of the WorkItemTypes in Project2, and examine the XML.  Look for the mentioned fields:

Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate, 
System.ExternalLinkCount,
System.HyperLinkCount, 
System.AttachedFileCount

And make sure the definition in your WorkItemType matches them.  It sounds like you may have either deleted or modified those fields somehow.

Comment: Why would I need Admin rights on Project2 when I am trying to import the WIT to Project1? Also, I haven't modified the XML in anyway. This works great on a vanilla TFS install but something's conflicting with the staging install I am trying to perform.

Comment: Looking at the error message, it looks like it was trying to import into Project2, not Project1.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields already exist in Project1. You are trying to import the same fields into Project2, but with different name="" and reportingtype="" settings.  Since you don't have permissions to change the definitions in Project1, the server is preventing you from uploading the type.

You have two options:

1. Get permissions to Project1 that allow you to change the field settings
2. Change the settings in your XML to match the settings from Project1.